# Inheriting the div height

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

I have following html snippet. I want the div which has background color as red to get the same height as the total of the divs with height 15.56 + 77.33 + 73.33

```
<body>
    <!-- outer div -->
    <div style="background-color:gray;">
        <div style="background-color: black; float: left;">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div style="height: 15.56px; background-color: blue;">Blue</div>
                    <div style="height: 77.33px; background-color: green;">Green</div>
                    <div style="height: 73.33px; background-color: orange;">Orange</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: red; display: inline-block; height: inherit;">
            Should be red!
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
```

[Image depicting how its appearing currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqgpg.png)

Comment: inherit is supposed to work between parent and child elements and not to the siblings

Answer (score 6):

Set [`display:flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to wrap div (then `float` not needed)

You tried to set `height: inherit;` and it didn't work because you want to set `height` to DOM as [sibling](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/) DOM and not as `parent`

> The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value
>   from its **parent** element.

```css
.outer{display:flex}
```

```html
<body>
    <!-- outer div -->
    <div style="background-color:gray;" class="outer"> 

        <div style="background-color: black;">
            <div> 
                <div> 
                    <div style="height: 15.56px; background-color: blue;">Blue</div> 
                    <div style="height: 77.33px; background-color: green;">Green</div> 
                    <div style="height: 73.33px; background-color: orange;">Orange</div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="background-color: red;"> 
                Should be red!
            </div>              
        </div>
    <body>
```

Comment: taht what you mean?

Comment: it seems like he doesn't know how to use height inherit. height inherit makes the height relative to the parent. He has no height attribute for the parent. he just doesn't understand what height inherit is. It is not what he thinks it is.

Comment: How about using   .outer{height:-webkit-fill-available;} ?

Comment: when the hight shall be defined by children (or grandchildren) nodes (blue, green, orange), the parent sibling (red) cannot know the height. But the css flex-property with all its additional functionality will solve your problem [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @jackblank I will add explain

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I was not asking about inherit keyword. I want the div which has the red background to inherit the total height of the previous div which is 166.22px. How can this be done? When I inspect the all the divs that contain the Blue, Green and Orange divs, the total height is correctly propogated.

Comment: It done with  `display:flex` to the wrap... as in snippet the red gets the total height ... or I did not get your question?

Comment: Thanks a lot  לבני מלכה , that worked! :) . I will try to modify the question summary so that it would be useful for others as well...

Comment: Thanks @Diwa for your suggestion